# Converting hex to decimal in awk or sed

Tags: sed, awk, decimal, hex

I have a list of numbers, comma-separated:

```
123711184642,02,3583090366663629,639f02012437d4
123715942138,01,3538710295145500,639f02afd6c643
123711616258,02,3548370476972758,639f0200485732
```

I need to split the 3rd column into three as below:

```
123711184642,02,3583090366663629,639f02,0124,37d4
123715942138,01,3538710295145500,639f02,afd6,c643
123711616258,02,3548370476972758,639f02,0048,5732
```

And convert the digits in the last two columns into decimal:

```
123711184642,02,3583090366663629,639f02,292,14292
123715942138,01,3538710295145500,639f02,45014,50755
123711616258,02,3548370476972758,639f02,72,22322
```

Comment: You meant you need to split the 4th column.

Comment: If you don't like the unneeded forks in bash scripts, here is a solution: let the hexa value in `$f`. Then the decimal value is `$[0x"$f"]`. No complex subshell-executed `"$(printf "%d" 0x"$f")"` and similars are needed.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Here's a variation on Jonathan's answer:

```bash
awk $([[ $(awk --version) = GNU* ]] && echo --non-decimal-data) -F, '
    BEGIN {OFS = FS}
    {
        $6 = sprintf("%d", "0x" substr($4, 11, 4))
        $5 = sprintf("%d", "0x" substr($4,  7, 4))
        $4 = substr($4,  1, 6)
        print
    }'
```

I included a rather contorted way of adding the [--non-decimal-data](//gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Nondecimal-Data) option if it's needed.

**Edit**

Just for the heck of it, here's the pure-Bash equivalent:

```bash
saveIFS=$IFS
IFS=,
while read -r -a line
do
    printf '%s,%s,%d,%d\n' "${line[*]:0:3}" "${line[3]:0:6}" "0x${line[3]:6:4}" "0x${line[3]:10:4}"
done
IFS=$saveIFS
```

The `"${line[*]:0:3}"` (quoted `*`) works similarly to AWK's `OFS` in that it causes Bash's `IFS` (here a comma) to be inserted between array elements on output. We can take further advantage of that feature by inserting array elements as follows which more closely parallels my AWK version above.

```bash
saveIFS=$IFS
IFS=,
while read -r -a line
do
    line[6]=$(printf '%d' "0x${line[3]:10:4}")
    line[5]=$(printf '%d' "0x${line[3]:6:4}")
    line[4]=$(printf '%s' "${line[3]:0:6}")
    printf '%s\n' "${line[*]}"
done
IFS=$saveIFS
```

Unfortunately, Bash doesn't allow `printf -v` (which is similar to `sprintf()`) to make assignments to array elements, so `printf -v "line[6]" ...` doesn't work.

**Edit:** As of Bash 4.1, `printf -v` can now make assignments to array elements. Example:

```bash
printf -v 'line[6]' '%d' "0x${line[3]:10:4}"
```

The quotes around the array reference are needed to prevent possible filename matching. If a file named "line6" existed in the current directory and the reference wasn't quoted, then a variable named `line6` would be created (or updated) containing the printf output. Nothing else about the file, such as its contents, would come into play. Only the name - and only tangentially.

Comment: `printf -v` to array elements was added in, I believe, Bash 4.1.

Comment: Nicely done; it's worth adding `2>/dev/null` to `awk --version`, because `mawk` will print an error message with `--version`.

Comment: Using `--non-decimal-data` is not recommended according to [GNU Awk User's Guide](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Nondecimal-Data.html). Alternatively, adding `-Wposix` option seems to work by all awk implementations available for Ubuntu Linux i.e. mawk, gawk and original-awk.

Comment: Since --non-decimal-data is not recommended according to the [GNU Awk User's Guide](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Nondecimal-Data), an alternative approach would be to use `printf '%d' strtonum("0x${line[3]:10:4}")`

Comment: @mklement0 : i played around, and this syntax seems to be "relatively" okay :::::::::::::::::: `[n/m/g]awk -Wv --version -Wversion`  :::::::::::: `mawk2` prints out `mawk 1.9.9.6, 21 Aug 2016,…`, `mawk1` :: `mawk 1.3.4 20200120`, `nawk` prints `nawk: unknown option -Wv ignored

awk version 20200816` and `gawk` prints `GNU Awk 5.2.1, API 3.2, (GNU MPFR 4.1.0-p13, GNU MP 6.2.1)…..`

Answer (score 15):

## Foreword

In this answer I address converting hex numbers by AWK in general, not specifically in the case of the question.

In the following examples the first field (i.e. `$1`) of each record given to the interpreter is converted. Only hexadecimal digits are allowed in the input, not the "0x" prefix.

## By GNU Awk arbitrary great hex values can be converted simply

If `gawk` is complied to use the GNU MPFR and GMP libraries, it can do arbitrary precision arithmetic numbers, when option `-M` is used.

```bash
gawk -M '{print strtonum("0x" $1)}'
```

## By AWK portably

Using `--non-decimal-data` for gawk is not recommended according to [GNU Awk User's Guide](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Nondecimal-Data.html). And also using `strtonum()` is not portable but it is supported by `gawk` only as far as I know. So lets look at alternatives:

### By user-defined function

Supposedly the most portable way of doing conversion is by a user-defined awk function [[reference](http://www.unix.com/302618249-post4.html)]:

```bash
function parsehex(V,OUT)
{
    if(V ~ /^0x/)  V=substr(V,3);

    for(N=1; N<=length(V); N++)
        OUT=(OUT*16) + H[substr(V, N, 1)]

    return(OUT)
}

BEGIN { for(N=0; N<16; N++)
        {  H[sprintf("%x",N)]=N; H[sprintf("%X",N)]=N } }

{ print parsehex($1) }
```

**Note**: You can convert greater hex numbers by replacing `return(OUT)` by `return(sprintf("%.0f", OUT))`, if your AWK interpreter does support only 32-bit integers; I could convert 0x20000000000000 = 2^53 this way. The function ignores possible "0x" prefix.

### By calling shell's printf

You could use this

```bash
awk '{cmd="printf %u 0x" $1; cmd | getline decimal; close(cmd); print decimal}'
```

but it is relatively slow as it requires starting a subshell. The following one is faster, if you have many newline-separated hexadecimal numbers to convert:

```bash
awk 'BEGIN{cmd="printf \"%u\n\""}{cmd=cmd " 0x" $1}END{while ((cmd | getline dec) > 0) { print dec }; close(cmd)}'
```

There might be a problem if very many arguments are added for the single printf command.

Also these methods have limitation on how large hex numbers they can convert. I could convert 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF = 2^64-1 in my system.

### By using AWK's printf (or sprintf)

In my experience the following works in Linux:

```bash
awk -Wposix '{ printf "%d\n", "0x" $1 }'
```

I tested it by `gawk`, `mawk` and `original-awk` in Ubuntu Linux 20.04. `gawk` requires `-Wposix` or `-Wnon-decimal-data` here. Other implementations may display a warning message about the option, but you can hide it by redirection directive `2>/dev/null` in shell. If you don't want to do that, you can make it use `-Wposix` merely with GNU Awk like this:

```bash
awk -Wversion 2>/dev/null | ( unset -v IFS; read -r word _; [ "$word" = GNU ] && exit 0 || exit 1 ) && gawk_option="-Wposix" || gawk_option=""
awk $gawk_option '{ printf "%d\n", "0x" $1 }'
```

**Note**: Yet again implementation or your interpreter does limit the maximum hex value that can be converted by this way. E.g. `mawk` in my system has maximum-integer 2147483647; this is told in standard error output of `mawk -Wversion` (at least for version 1.3.4). You can convert greater hex numbers by replacing `printf "%d\n", "0x" $1` by `printf "%.0f\n", "0x" $1`; I could convert 0x20000000000000 = 2^53 this way; the limit is same in both ways when using Gawk, in my experience.

### If you just want to calculate with the converted value

Similarly to above, you could use explicit conversion:

`awk -Wnon-decimal-data '{s="0x"$1; d=0+s}'`

Now the converted value is in variable `d` but you might need to use some formatting to output it anyway.

Comment: This works in "original-awk" because it works without `-W posix` _unless_ it's gawk; gawk requires `-W posix`. This includes mawk 1.3.3 on Debian system as well as FreeBSD 7.3's awk 20070501 and FreeBSD 11.2's awk 20121220.

Comment: @jarno : you can simplify that to just : ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::  :::::::::::::::: ::::::::::::  ::::::::::::: ::::::::::::::::::: ::::::::::::: `echo 0xEDCFAB | mawk '$++NF = +$!_'` ——> `0xEDCFAB 15585195`. For larger inputs, do `echo 0xEDCFAB9877787 | mawk '$++NF = +$!_' CONVFMT='%.250g'
0xEDCFAB9877787 4183619086546823`. If you insist on `gawk` but wanna avoid `gawk -n`, then use `gawk -P` instead

Comment: @RAREKpopManifesto oh, I noticed that my answer does not work by larger inputs by all implementations. I'll try to improve my answer.

Comment: @RAREKpopManifesto `echo 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFF | mawk '$++NF = +$!_' CONVFMT='%.250g'` prints an even number number which is wrong, so you have to be careful even with that kind of method, if the input is large enough. As Awk seems to use floating point conversion in this case, it is important to analyze how big numbers it can handle accurately.

Comment: @jarno : i said larger, i didn't say "big int". For those you need `gawk -nMbe`. Fewer than 16 decimal digits, `mawk` is fine, beyond that but it's encountering the same limit as everyone else : `2 ^ 53 - 1`

Comment: @RAREKpopManifesto I could even convert `2^53` without `--bignum` or even `2^64-1` when using shell's `printf`.

Comment: @jarno : you want `2^64-1` in `awk` it's ultra easy if you're on `gawk` or `mawk2` - just `sprintf("%u", -1)`. my faith in shell `printf` has been seriously shaken considering how many bugs i reported just to `zsh` alone regarding that feature

Comment: @jarno : and you're changing the subject already, since the original question only hex decoding of smaller sized numbers - unlimited hex length wasn't part of the requirement. but you can always do `gawk -nMbe '$_+=_'` for ***unlimited*** length hex decoding

Comment: @RAREKpopManifesto I meant I could convert even 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF to decimal number when using shell's `printf`. I use dash as system shell,  and I suppose AWK follows that system setting. Also maybe the settings used for building the system matter.

Answer (score 11):

This seems to work:

```bash
awk -F, '{ p1 =       substr($4,  1, 6);
           p2 = ("0x" substr($4,  7, 4)) + 0;
           p3 = ("0x" substr($4, 11, 4)) + 0;
           printf "%s,%s,%s,%s,%d,%d\n", $1, $2, $3, p1, p2, p3;
         }'
```

For your sample input data, it produces:

```
123711184642,02,3583090366663629,639f02,292,14292
123715942138,01,3538710295145500,639f02,45014,50755
123711616258,02,3548370476972758,639f02,72,22322
```

The string concatenation of '0x' plus the 4-digit hex followed by adding 0 forces `awk` to treat the numbers as hexadecimals.

You can simplify this to:

```bash
awk -F, '{ p1 =      substr($4,  1, 6);
           p2 = "0x" substr($4,  7, 4);
           p3 = "0x" substr($4, 11, 4);
           printf "%s,%s,%s,%s,%d,%d\n", $1, $2, $3, p1, p2, p3;
         }'
```

The strings prefixed with 0x are forced to integer when presented to `printf()` and the `%d` format.

---

The code above works beautifully with the native `awk` on MacOS X 10.6.5 (version 20070501); sadly, it does not work with GNU `gawk` 3.1.7.  That, it seems, is permitted behaviour according to POSIX (see the comments below).  However, `gawk` has a non-standard function `strtonum` that can be used to bludgeon it into performing correctly - pity that bludgeoning is necessary.

```bash
gawk -F, '{ p1 =      substr($4,  1, 6);
            p2 = "0x" substr($4,  7, 4);
            p3 = "0x" substr($4, 11, 4);
            printf "%s,%s,%s,%s,%d,%d\n", $1, $2, $3, p1, strtonum(p2), strtonum(p3);
          }'
```

Comment: I'm getting zeros in the last 2 columns. 123711184642,02,3583090366663629,639f02,0,0
123715942138,01,3538710295145500,639f02,0,0
123711616258,02,3548370476972758,639f02,0,0

Comment: Which version of `awk` on which platform?  I'm using MacOS X 10.6.5 and its awk - version 20070501; when I use gawk 3.1.7, it gives zeroes.  That's worth a bug report to GNU.  I'll work on a workaround...

Comment: I'm getting similar results on Redhat Linux 2.6 and SunOS 5.10 using GNU Awk 3.1.5

Comment: @bernie: The first version will work with `gawk` if you use the `--non-decimal-data` option.

Comment: @Dennis: you shouldn't have to twist gawk's arm so hard to get it to work!

Comment: I don't disagree, but `info gawk` claims it's for backwards compatibility.

Comment: @Dennis: ugh - I'd have to go find an old AT&T awk to check it all out.  Oh well, maybe the putative bug report would fall on ... well, not exactly deaf ears, but it would be rejected.  I wonder what the POSIX awk specification says?  I don't have the time to look now, though.

Comment: POSIX says it's implementation-specific.

Comment: @Dennis: ugh - as bad as it gets!  Basically, there were some that did and some that didn't, and no-one could make their mind up.  Grumble.

Answer (score 3):

```bash
printf "%d\n", strtonum( "0x"$1 )"
```

Comment: Works by `gawk` only.

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed & printf):

```bash
sed -r 's/(....)(....)$/ 0x\1 0x\2/;s/.*/printf "%s,%d,%d" &/e' file
```

Split the last eight characters and add spaces preceeding the fields by the hex identifier and then evaluate the whole line using printf.

Answer (score 0):

```bash
cat all_info_List.csv| awk 'BEGIN {FS="|"}{print $21}'| awk 'BEGIN {FS=":"}{p1=$1":"$2":"$3":"$4":"$5":";  p2 = strtonum("0x"$6); printf("%s%02X\n",p1,p2+1) }'
```

The above command prints the contents of "all_info_List.csv", a file where the field separator is "|".
Then takes field 21 (MAC address) and splits it using field separator ":".
It assigns to variable "`p1`" the first 5 bytes of each mac address, so if we had this mac address:"11:22:33:44:55:66", `p1` would be: "11:22:33:44:55:".
`p2` is assigned with the decimal value of the last byte: "0x66" would assign "102" decimal to `p2`.
Finally, I'm using `printf` to join `p1` and `p2`, while converting `p2` back to hex, after adding one to it.

Comment: strtonum() works by gawk only; not by e.g mawk to which awk may be symlinked to.

Answer (score 0):

### --- My 5 Cents

I just want to add my 5 Cents in case this topic is still of interest. From the comments in the thread
I take it, there still is. Hope it helps:

Challenge: Convert a hex number to decimal on a Apple M1 laptop running the latest MacOS (2022)
With the following versions on MacOS

```
% uname -a
Darwin macbook 22.1.0 Darwin Kernel Version 22.1.0: Sun Oct  9 20:15:09 PDT 2022; root:xnu-8792.41.9~2/RELEASE_ARM64_T6000 arm64 arm Darwin

% gawk --version
GNU Awk 5.2.1, API 3.2, (GNU MPFR 4.1.0-p13, GNU MP 6.2.1)
Copyright (C) 1989, 1991-2022 Free Software Foundation.
```

### --- gawk -Wposix needed

```
% echo "116B" | gawk '{p = ("0x" substr($1, 1, 4)) +0; printf("%d\n", p )}'
0

% echo "116B" | gawk -Wposix '{p = ("0x" substr($1, 1, 4)) +0; printf("%d\n", p )}'
4459
```

### --- Some simplifications also work

```
% echo "116B" | gawk -Wposix '{p = "0x" substr($1, 1, 4); printf("%d\n", p )}'
4459

% echo "116B" | gawk -Wposix '{printf("%d\n", "0x" substr($1, 1, 4))}'
4459
```

### --- Checking...

```
% echo "4459" | gawk '{printf("%X\n", $1 )}'
116B
```

### --- This form is what I was looking for

```
% echo "00:11:6BX" | gawk -Wposix '{printf("%d\n", "0x" substr($1, 1, 2) substr($1, 4, 2) substr($1, 7, 2))}'
4459
```

Answer (score 0):

this should be a cleaner approach than `perl` `python` or `printf` :

```
echo 0x7E07E30EAAC59DB8EB9FDAD2EE818EA7AEB70192DAE552AD06B9FE
       593BE89BC258483EA07C972B0FE7BA0D7B6CAC6DF338571F49CABB
       DD195629411CDF0F88858EC39F01AE181E60A4F0DAF5F4F0E86991
       82243BDF159AB588F11E3FF68E799509128EA7BA957B62DF103D0E
       B2C3195DA1CCDFDD0CAF0E9958C1AF3E2B6993AA74C255B711BE38
       DB031B26A596EFE19051A864000FB99F161923F12C2F9F40F18B6E
       064CCCAE4C0776D0EB815947A30AB68B1CF12CA6622CAECA530221
       2C27FD1579178363FE2E87B1F02FC0FDFFF |
```

> ```
> gawk -nMbe '$++NF = +$!_' OFS='\n\n'
> ```

```
 1  0x7E07E30EAAC59DB8EB9FDAD2EE818EA7AEB70192DAE552AD06B9FE
      593BE89BC258483EA07C972B0FE7BA0D7B6CAC6DF338571F49CABB
      DD195629411CDF0F88858EC39F01AE181E60A4F0DAF5F4F0E86991
      82243BDF159AB588F11E3FF68E799509128EA7BA957B62DF103D0E
      B2C3195DA1CCDFDD0CAF0E9958C1AF3E2B6993AA74C255B711BE38
      DB031B26A596EFE19051A864000FB99F161923F12C2F9F40F18B6E
      064CCCAE4C0776D0EB815947A30AB68B1CF12CA6622CAECA530221
      2C27FD1579178363FE2E87B1F02FC0FDFFF

 2  985801769662049290799836483751359680713382803597807741
      342261221390727037343867491391068497002991150267570021
      888625408701957708383236015057159917981445085171196540
      056449671723413767151987807183076995694938175592905407
      706727043644590485574826597324100590757487981303537403
      481578192766548120367625144822345612103264180960846560
      558546717739085751660018602037450619797709845938562717
      870137791128285871274530893277287577788311030033741131
      093413810677239057304751530532826551215693481438241043
      55789791231
```

in case you're wondering, this number is a Mersenne prime to the power of another Mersenne prime :

> ```
> 8191 ^ 127
> ```

And the 2 primes closest to it should be

- ```
   8191 ^ 127 - ( 16 + 512 )
  ```
- ```
   8191 ^ 127 + (     1450 )
  ```

Comment: Well that `gawk` command looks a bit obscure, but it works anyway, because `-n` option is still around; I would use `strtonum()`, instead.

Comment: @jarno : `gawk -nMbe '$++NF = +$!_' OFS='\n\n'` :::: the `-n` flag for auto decoding of hex and octals; `-M` flag for bignum via `gnu GMP`; `-b` flag for byte code (much faster startup and processing, esp when u don't need unicode); `$++NF = ` is to assign the output into a new field after the right most one instead of overwriting any parts of the input; ……...

Comment: @jarno : ….. `+$!_` is same as `+$1`, which is same as `$1 + 0` without the verbosity, and since the input is already in the form `0x7E07E3….` , this is basically same as doing `$( NF + 1 ) = +"0x7E07E3….."`, which assigns the decimal integer of that hex into the new field, then print the whole thing. Finally, `OFS='\n\n'` simply means i want the output printed on a different line instead of appended on the same line, with a line gap in between.

Comment: @jarno : issue with `strtonum()` is that it fails on negative hex input like `"-0xABCD"`, but the `-n` handles it properly

Answer (score -1):

Perl version, with a tip of the hat to @Jonathan:

```bash
perl -F, -lane '$p1 = substr($F[3], 0, 6); $p2 = substr($F[3], 6, 4); $p3 = substr($F[3], 10, 4); printf "%s,%s,%s,%s,%d,%d\n", @F[0..2], $p1, hex($p2), hex($p3)' file
```

`-a` turn on autosplit mode, to populate the `@F` array
`-F,` changes the autosplit separator to `,` (default is whitespace)
The `substr()` indices are 1 less than their awk equivalents, since Perl arrays start from 0.

Output:

```
123711184642,02,3583090366663629,639f02,292,14292
123715942138,01,3538710295145500,639f02,45014,50755
123711616258,02,3548370476972758,639f02,72,22322
```