# how to input and output in hexadecimal format in awk?

Tags: awk

I have a file like this :

```
0000000 4130b00f adfbad7e ad96adbc ada0ad6e ad91adf4 ae2eae9e 3b64b1bc ab89a4b0  A0.....~.......n........;d......
0000020 a3c0a865 a18ba57e a721a531 a608a64e a807aaf9 ae6ba418 ac2938c2 ad23abb6  ...e...~.!.1...N.....k...)8..#..
0000040 2cd6a1d9 3f583428 a4e1a659 a2eca7e1 4116aa10 2d5433ff 29483114 30153ac8  ,...?X4(...Y....A...-T3.)H1.0.:.
0000060 37ab3cfd a9fca910 adb13542 9dec8b99 3d752fde 340230c3 2eeb33bd 33d83a5a  7.<.......5B....=u/.4.0...3.3.:Z
0000080 38aab0b1 349ca9cf b0603e00 3b2839ea a6082f4d 2c7c9df9 3d4630aa a90f3936  8...4....`>.;(9.../M,|..=F0...96
00000a0 a6081fb0 b0a13c1c a2cc39d2 b17caa7c a5f62ada 3321a9bd a1a9aefe 36099f1c  ......<...9..|.|..*.3!......6...
00000c0 3b10a326 3806ae88 acde9fdc a3a630a0 3d562e82 a4a12e85 390e35aa a5902078  ;..&8.........0.=V......9.5... x
00000e0 ac6329d6 36263802 33983c16 303ea8f8 a5302eb3 34ee35e8 a4adaaec 34d19bb3  .c).6&8.3.<.0>...0..4.5.....4...
0000100 2c793183 325c3990 a4e9a678 303a35e4 2ebb3067 3590346e 31613724 31b6a817  ,y1.2\9....x0:5...0g5.4n1a7$1...
0000120 39b68800 a83b31d0 30e4353d 350d3892 33e32d22 2b8ea5e9 b7f1334e 353834e4  9....;1.0.5=5.8.3.-"+.....3N584.
0000140 351a37f3 38a63930 38d23884 38c43c3c 41bc36fa 3dd838fb 3932397e 3b283bde  5.7.8.908.8.8.<<A.6.=.8.929~;(;.
0000160 3ae03b94 3c113c28 3c47aedb 3b1c3d17 39283c51 414039ad 3ae13930 39013b5a  :.;.<.<(<G..;.=.9(<QA@9.:.909.;Z
0000180 39db3a33 43dca99b ac919fd9 3fb5a204 311899c6 a7e332ac 3882a703 9d569c63  9.:3C.......?...1.....2.8....V.c
```

the first column, 0000000, 0000020, 0000040, are the address of the following data. I want to add certain number for example 0x258d5580 to this address and display it, so that it looks like this :

```
258d5580 4130b00f adfbad7e ad96adbc ada0ad6e ad91adf4 ae2eae9e 3b64b1bc ab89a4b0  A0.....~.......n........;d......
258d55a0 a3c0a865 a18ba57e a721a531 a608a64e a807aaf9 ae6ba418 ac2938c2 ad23abb6  ...e...~.!.1...N.....k...)8..#..
258d55c0 2cd6a1d9 3f583428 a4e1a659 a2eca7e1 4116aa10 2d5433ff 29483114 30153ac8  ,...?X4(...Y....A...-T3.)H1.0.:.
258d55e0 37ab3cfd a9fca910 adb13542 9dec8b99 3d752fde 340230c3 2eeb33bd 33d83a5a  7.<.......5B....=u/.4.0...3.3.:Z
258d5600 38aab0b1 349ca9cf b0603e00 3b2839ea a6082f4d 2c7c9df9 3d4630aa a90f3936  8...4....`>.;(9.../M,|..=F0...96
258d5620 a6081fb0 b0a13c1c a2cc39d2 b17caa7c a5f62ada 3321a9bd a1a9aefe 36099f1c  ......<...9..|.|..*.3!......6...
258d5640 3b10a326 3806ae88 acde9fdc a3a630a0 3d562e82 a4a12e85 390e35aa a5902078  ;..&8.........0.=V......9.5... x
258d5660 ac6329d6 36263802 33983c16 303ea8f8 a5302eb3 34ee35e8 a4adaaec 34d19bb3  .c).6&8.3.<.0>...0..4.5.....4...
258d5680 2c793183 325c3990 a4e9a678 303a35e4 2ebb3067 3590346e 31613724 31b6a817  ,y1.2\9....x0:5...0g5.4n1a7$1...
258d56a0 39b68800 a83b31d0 30e4353d 350d3892 33e32d22 2b8ea5e9 b7f1334e 353834e4  9....;1.0.5=5.8.3.-"+.....3N584.
258d56c0 351a37f3 38a63930 38d23884 38c43c3c 41bc36fa 3dd838fb 3932397e 3b283bde  5.7.8.908.8.8.<<A.6.=.8.929~;(;.
258d56e0 3ae03b94 3c113c28 3c47aedb 3b1c3d17 39283c51 414039ad 3ae13930 39013b5a  :.;.<.<(<G..;.=.9(<QA@9.:.909.;Z
258d5700 39db3a33 43dca99b ac919fd9 3fb5a204 311899c6 a7e332ac 3882a703 9d569c63  9.:3C.......?...1.....2.8....V.c
258d5720 aa2bb218 a4cd34b9 ad02a5ad 38d64336 34d4b025 390a3939 3628ad3e b03a3f9f  .+....4.....8.C64..%9.996(.>.:?.
258d5740 3ad73724 2f0336a6 b244ad12 a9f6af7c aa70ace3 ab8eabf8 ae693be2 af41af41  :.7$/.6..D.....|.p.......i;..A.A
```

how can I do this using awk?
my awk version :

```
ckim@stph45:/home/ckim] awk --version
GNU Awk 3.1.7
Copyright (C) 1989, 1991-2009 Free Software Foundation.
```

ADD (solved for me) : This works (with help from tripleee below)
tt.awk :

```
{ $1 = sprintf("%08x", $1 + 0x258d5580) } 1
```

and do

```
awk -f tt.awk --non-decimal-data file
```

it works.

```
258d5580 4130b00f adfbad7e ad96adbc ada0ad6e ad91adf4 ae2eae9e 3b64b1bc ab89a4b0 A0.....~.......n........;d......
258d55a0 a3c0a865 a18ba57e a721a531 a608a64e a807aaf9 ae6ba418 ac2938c2 ad23abb6 ...e...~.!.1...N.....k...)8..#..
258d55c0 2cd6a1d9 3f583428 a4e1a659 a2eca7e1 4116aa10 2d5433ff 29483114 30153ac8 ,...?X4(...Y....A...-T3.)H1.0.:.
258d55e0 37ab3cfd a9fca910 adb13542 9dec8b99 3d752fde 340230c3 2eeb33bd 33d83a5a 7.<.......5B....=u/.4.0...3.3.:Z
258d5600 38aab0b1 349ca9cf b0603e00 3b2839ea a6082f4d 2c7c9df9 3d4630aa a90f3936 8...4....`>.;(9.../M,|..=F0...96
258d5620 a6081fb0 b0a13c1c a2cc39d2 b17caa7c a5f62ada 3321a9bd a1a9aefe 36099f1c ......<...9..|.|..*.3!......6...
258d5640 3b10a326 3806ae88 acde9fdc a3a630a0 3d562e82 a4a12e85 390e35aa a5902078 ;..&8.........0.=V......9.5... x
258d5660 ac6329d6 36263802 33983c16 303ea8f8 a5302eb3 34ee35e8 a4adaaec 34d19bb3 .c).6&8.3.<.0>...0..4.5.....4...
258d5680 2c793183 325c3990 a4e9a678 303a35e4 2ebb3067 3590346e 31613724 31b6a817 ,y1.2\9....x0:5...0g5.4n1a7$1...
258d56a0 39b68800 a83b31d0 30e4353d 350d3892 33e32d22 2b8ea5e9 b7f1334e 353834e4 9....;1.0.5=5.8.3.-"+.....3N584.
258d56c0 351a37f3 38a63930 38d23884 38c43c3c 41bc36fa 3dd838fb 3932397e 3b283bde 5.7.8.908.8.8.<<A.6.=.8.929~;(;.
258d56e0 3ae03b94 3c113c28 3c47aedb 3b1c3d17 39283c51 414039ad 3ae13930 39013b5a :.;.<.<(<G..;.=.9(<QA@9.:.909.;Z
258d5700 39db3a33 43dca99b ac919fd9 3fb5a204 311899c6 a7e332ac 3882a703 9d569c63 9.:3C.......?...1.....2.8....V.c
258d5720 aa2bb218 a4cd34b9 ad02a5ad 38d64336 34d4b025 390a3939 3628ad3e b03a3f9f .+....4.....8.C64..%9.996(.>.:?.
```

Comment: od and awk combined may be an easier way i will explain later when i can do typing on my laptop

Comment: This question is a duplicate but not in a direct way: The OP can use the duplicate to solve his problem in the following way: `awk '{v=("0x"$1); v=strtonum(v)+0x258d5580; $1=sprintf("%0.8x",v)}1' file`

Answer (score 2):

Try this.

```
awk '{ $1 = sprintf("%08x", ("0x" $1) + "0x258d5580") } 1' file
```

Your Awk might require an option `--non-decimal-data` before the script text.

Also, I found on MacOS Mojave that I had to use "0x..." around the hex number to make it a string; the OP reports the opposite. If portability is important, perhaps look into using a language which is more uniform across platforms, like perhaps Python or Perl.

```
perl -pe 's/^([0-9a-f]+)/ sprintf("%08x", oct("0x$&")+0x258d5580) /e' file
```

Comment: Hi, the result is : the first column is all 00000000. Isn't there an error in your suggention?

Comment: and when I do awk '{ $1 = sprintf("%08x", ("0x" $1) + 0x258d5580) } 1' file, the first column is all 258d5580 not incrementing by 0x20.

Comment: by the way, what is the '1' at the end? without it, awk prints nothing. and thanks for trying to help me.

Comment: First google hit: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/63891/what-is-the-meaning-of-1-at-the-end-of-awk-script

Comment: Based on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4614775/converting-hex-to-decimal-in-awk-or-sed try adding the option `--non-decimal-data`.  Demo: http://ideone.com/WIf4Ex

Comment: I was just going to write this. Awk knows numbers such as `0x258d5580`, but if they arrive as strings--which is what `("0x"$1)` is in the end, awk has it very difficult. `--non-decimal-data` fixes that.

Comment: ok, thanks both. That does the trick! I tried " awk -f tt.awk --non-decimal-data aa1" and tt.awk contains "{printf("%x %s %s %s %s %s %s %s %s %s\n", $1 + 0x2586bb80, $2,$3,$4,$5,$6,$7,$8,$9,$10);}". @tripleee why don't you modify your answer? and I'll select your answer.

Comment: From [Posix](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/awk.html): _Historical implementations of awk did not parse hexadecimal integer or floating constants like "0xa" and "0xap0". Due to an oversight, the 2001 through 2004 editions of this standard required support for hexadecimal floating constants. This was due to the reference to atof(). This version of the standard allows but does not require implementations to use atof() and includes a description of how floating-point numbers are recognized as an alternative to match historic behavior._

Comment: ... _The intent of this change is to allow implementations to recognize floating-point constants according to either the ISO/IEC 9899:1990 standard or ISO/IEC 9899:1999 standard, and to allow (but not require) implementations to recognize hexadecimal integer constants._

Comment: Modifying `$1` and printing the whole line is vastly preferable to the long list of arguments iMHO. You are too impatient; I updated already.

Comment: which awk are you using? I couldn't make this work without `-n` option on GNU awk 5.0.1

Comment: This works for me on Mac OS Mojave out of the box (Awk version 20070501) , and on Ideone (Ubuntu 19.04, GNU Awk 4.2.1) with the `--non-decimal-data` option.

Comment: Posix awk versions can process hexadecimal strings. GNU awk does not allow it as it could break old programs. You get the same effect when writing `-Wposix` instead of `--non-decimal-data`.

Comment: See [GNU awk manual: Section _Allowing Nondecimal Input Data_](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Nondecimal-Data) for some more info.

Comment: `--non-decimal-data` is deprecated, use `strtonum()` in gawk instead.

Comment: Hi, I'm the OP. @tripleee , if I do exactly what you suggest, it doesn't work for me. But if I modify your suggestion to tt.awk : { $1 = sprintf("%08x", $1 + 0x258d5580) } 1  and do `awk -f tt.awk --non-decimal-data file`  it works. The ("0x" $1) + "0x258d5580"  should be just $1 + 0x258d5580 in my case.

Comment: @tripleee please add my tweak as an option so I can select you answer.

Comment: See update now.

Answer (score 1):

You would better use a tool that understand hexadecimal binary dump like xxd (tool part of vim package).

The following command will reformat the hex dump file as binary and back to text:

```
xxd -c 32 -r -s 0x258d5580 hexdumpfile | xxd -c 36 -g 4 -s 0x258d5580
```

Options explanation:

`-c` number of bytes per column
`-r` reverse operation (takes hex dump and convert it to binary)
`-g` number of bytes to group together
`-s` number of bytes to skip (seek function)