How to account the number of persons satisfying some condition in a CSV
i have a table, say 1.csv, having a name and presence/absence at the 1st, 2nd, 3rd, 4th days, like..
name,1st,2nd,3rd,4th
Alice,1,1,0,0
bob,0,1,1,1
Clara,1,0,1,0

To reduce the number of columns, I replaced these four-flag attribute to hex numbered attribute (say 2.csv), like
name,hex
alice,c
bob,7
clara,a

I have another table the column contents are horizontally spread with only a single row (say, 3.csv) like
alice,c,bob,7,clara,a

I would like to extract the number of persons who attended, e.g., the third day.
I prefer doing this task with MS Excel. How to implement it?
Thanks in advance,
I think the following Excel built-in functions can do the task,
=DEC2BIN(HEX2DEC(B2), 4)
=MID(DEC2BIN(HEX2DEC(B2), 4), 3, 1)
=COUNTIF(C2:C4, "1")

I prefer doing this task also with awk/bash if it works. Please advice!

Do you want to use csv file 1 2 or 3?

See here for the conversion https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4614775/converting-hex-to-decimal-in-awk-or-sed

please update the question with your awk and/or bash coding attempts

You can only prefer 1 thing.  Excel or bash?  Change tags on your question based on that.

In Excel you can use HEX2DEC  and BITAND. You just need to translate that your comparators for {1,2,3,4}  would be {8,4,2,1}

i'd like to get a table headed with project-name and number-Of-Persons-For-3rd, because Alice et al. are the members of some project (say, project 1). the copilot proposed to use =--(MID(DEC2BIN(HEX2DEC(B2), 4), 3, 1)="1") + --(MID(DEC2BIN(HEX2DEC(D2), 4), 3, 1)="1") + --(MID(DEC2BIN(HEX2DEC(F2), 4), 3, 1)="1"). Is this OK?

Do you want an Excel answer or a Unix (bash, awk) answer? Also please answer the first question you were asked in comments above - for your input Do you want to use csv file 1 2 or 3?.

@user15181 " Is this OK?" If it worked for you than it is. If it did not, then it is not. But neither the csv you are using, nor how you are getting the table headers (eg project name) are defined in your question, making it difficult to provide you a solution, unless someone guesses your actual situation.

replaced these four-flag attribute to hex numbered did you documented that properly, so future user will know if he should use little endian or middle endian or big endian?

Not sure what you want or which data set you are using.
But in Excel (assuming no version constraints per your tags), using your table (3.csv), you can obtain the attendance day 3 from this formula:
=LET(
    spl, TEXTSPLIT(A1, ","),
    cnt, COLUMNS(spl) / 2,
    att, HEX2DEC(
        INDEX(spl, 1, SEQUENCE(, cnt, 2, 2))
    ),
    _day3, SUM(
        BYCOL(
            att,
            LAMBDA(arr, IF(BITAND(2, arr), 1))
        )
    ),
    _day3
)


Split the string by commas
Count the number of elements (allows for any number of people
Extract the even number elements which is the attendance record
Convert Hex to Decimal
Analyze for setting of the 2nd bit from the right with the BITAND function and sum the results.


Should you want to use different outputs or inputs, please be specific.
If your csv.3 table elements are in separate cells, a minor change in the formula will accomodate:
=LET(
    data, A2:F2,
    n, COLUMNS(data),
    att, HEX2DEC(
        INDEX(
            data,
            1,
            SEQUENCE(, n / 2, 2, 2)
        )
    ),
    _day3, SUM(
        BYCOL(
            att,
            LAMBDA(arr, IF(BITAND(2, arr), 1))
        )
    ),
    _day3
)



From you  1.csv you can get attendance for 3rd day with
awk -F, 'NR>1 {c+=$4} END {print c}' 1.csv


I appreciate your response.

Using GNU awk (for bitwise and() and while using gawk anyway strtonum(), too) to get the number of attendees from the file 3.csv:
The problem in that format is that we don't know the exact number of days the event lasted, so 4 days is assumed and therefore constant (2^4=) 16 is used. This could of course be parameterized as well.
$ gawk -v d=3 '
BEGIN {
    FS=","                                # delimiter
    d=16/2^d                              # figuring out a value for and()
}
{
    for(i=2;i<=NF;i+=2)                   # iterating hex bitfields
        s+=(and(strtonum("0x" $i),d)&&1)  # the logic behind the solution is logic
}
END {
    print s
}' 3.csv

Output is the number of attendees on the 3rd day:
2

From 1.csv to 2.csv (as I misread the question first):
$ awk '
BEGIN {
    FS=","
}
{
    for(i=2;i<=NF;i++)
        s=2*s+$i
    printf "%s,"(NR==1?"hex":"%x")"\n",$1,s
    s=0
}' 1.csv # > 2.csv

name,hex
Alice,c
bob,7
Clara,a


"the logic behind the solution is logic" - reminds me of when I worked at a large firm that had just gone through layoffs and at a company meeting someone asked the CEO if there were plans for more layoffs and she replied "we have no plans beyond our current plans" which I thought was a brilliant answer compared to "yes" (we then went through 10+ more years of monthly layoffs).

@EdMorton Those corporate downsizing consultants sure paid off. :D I worked for a telco for 10+ years. Same atmos-fear.

my thought has been updated and now i am seeking other way than hex code based approach. Should I delete this post?
